# Get the Log Sequence Number of individual rows in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, replication, database-replication

Hello all :) I'm building some kind of delta replication from MySQL InnoDB to a NoSQL system. What I want is to select rows that need to be refreshed to the target NoSQL system.

In Oracle we conveniently have an `ora_rowscn` attached to each row. It gives an upper bound of the System Change Number (SCN) of the row. This number is the equivalent of the Log Sequence Number (LSN) of MySQL. We can use it to know if a row needs to be sent to the target NoSQL system (by storing the max SCN/LSN of the last update).

So the question is: If I want to replicate a MySQL table, how can I select the lines that have been updated since a specific LSN?

Best regards

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because this is about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "standard" approach:

1. Add an `UpdatedAt` column.
2. Maintain the `updatedAt` column using a trigger.
3. When you copy data over, take all records modified since the last `UpdatedAt` date.

Alternatively, there may be solution to replicate MySQL to a NoSQL database.